# Express.js Middleware - Adding items to the response object model

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm playing around with Expressjs and am attempting to extract the page title from the default template to middleware instead of passed into the view's model each time.

**Default index.jade template**

```
h1= title

p Welcome to the #{title}
```

**Default route from template**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: "Express" });
};
```

I attempted the following but get an error from Express saying `title` is undefined when I do this.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    res.title = 'Express';
    next();
}
```

This is obviously a trivial example but it's also something that I am trying to figure out since there will probably come a time where I want to inject things into the response's model after each route.  I just cannot figure out how to do such.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use default helpers. Read [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.helpers%28%29). Here's a simple snippet:

```
app.helpers({
    title: 'Express'
});
/* Now JADE sees your variable title
   without explicitly defining it
   in every view. */
```

Also look at *dynamic helpers* in the documentation. These can be linked to `req` and `res` variables (normal helpers do not depend on request/response).